# Проблема с SqLite в Android

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема при программирование под Android базы данных.

Вот запрос на создание базы данных

```
 String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "Contact" + "("
         + Contact[0] + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Contact[1] + " INTEGER,"+ Contact[2] + " TEXT,"
         + Contact[3] + " INTEGER," + Contact[4]+" TEXT,"+Contact[5]+" TEXT,"+Contact[6]+" INTEGER,"+Contact[7]+" INTEGER,"+Contact[8]+" INTEGER,"+
         Contact[9]+" TEXT,"+Contact[10]+" Integer"+
         ");";
 db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);
```

Он работает и создает базу.

Далее следует запрос базу данных который работает мягко говоря странно.

```
 public long addContact(String []newContact) {
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 for(int i=0;i<newContact.length;i++)
 values.put(Contact[i],newContact[i]);
 long l= db.insert("Contact", null, values);
 return l;
 }
```

ContentValues values перемешивает значения странным образом и не всегда корректно. 
Из-за этого при работе возникают критические ошибки.

Как можно это исправить? 
Дополнительно он должен возвращать id добавленного контакта. По умолчанию insert Возвращает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь руками задать первичный ключ `contact[0]` во время вставки. Он у вас объявлен как `autoincrement`, так что его не нужно задавать.

Попробуйте так:

```
for(int i=1;i<newContact.length;i++) //начните с 1
 values.put(Contact[i],newContact[i]);
```

Comment: Тут в другом проблема, в ContentValues значения заносятся в неправильном порядке.

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Спасибо)

Comment: Слушайся старших!